# Shopify: How to call a Javascript function when a product is added to cart?

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

I am looking for a solution about how to call a javascript function when an item is added to cart on shopify via ajax. Product can be added from homepage, collection-page or product-page.

I am trying with this method but not working for me. These changes i am doing within the theme files "theme.liquid, product.liquid, collection.liquid"

```
  Shopify.onItemAdded = function(cart) {
    alert('yass');
  };
```

Comment: Did you include this `{{ 'api.jquery.js' | shopify_asset_url | script_tag }}`?

Comment: This line already included in theme footer.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032011/shopify-how-to-call-a-javascript-function-when-a-product-is-added-to-cart